# Need a book on Graduate Complex Analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

Is there a book on complex analysis that deals with the same topic as the 3rd chapter of Nevanlinna Paatero's  "Introduction to Complex Analysis" but more rigorously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex Analysis by Serge Lang, Chapter 7: Conformal Mappings.

Comment: Thank you,Steve. I will check the book soon.